# Unix command to find files read by specific user

Tags: unix

I would like to find files accessed by specific user (even just read) within a folder tree. I thought the `find` command had this option, but it actually just searches for owner user. Is there any other command, or command combinations? The `stat` command offers access information, but doesn't display the user who made access.

Comment: @DeerHunter true, I would move the question to the Unix SE, though several questions about Unix are often answered in SO

Comment: If one is talking about Linux, it is possible to set up notifications and/or enable logging through `auditd`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable the [audit subsystem](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html) before you can monitor file accesses. This may have a noticeable effect on system performance.